# Why are the prints going diagonal

Tags: c#, rendering, command-prompt

This is my code

```
        int ultra = 0;
        int hydra = 999;

        while (1 < 2)
        {
            Console.Write(ultra);
            ultra++;
            Console.Write($"                                                                    {hydra}");
        }
```

as you see i indent alot in the {hydra} part, thats because i wanted 2 seperate lines (which is also why i used console.write) But what i am getting is this[image]

Then after around 99 Billion this is what i get

[image]

But why
1.In the beginning they are diagonal
2. They become 3 straight lines in the end
3. Why 3 straight lines and not 2?
This makes no sense can someone please explain what is happening here?
Note: Even if i make them Console.WriteLine, they still go diagonally

Edit: i figured out that they go diagonal because i didnt add a linebreak, but i still dont understand why would they straigthen into 3 lines at over "99billion"

Comment: First of all you are running an infinite loop, this may crash the application

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. Your question has a low quality. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the number of digits in your number is increasing, so you can't use a fixed length of indents. If I understand what you're trying to do correctly (which I probably don't, what exactly is the goal here?), this should be the way to go:

```
        int ultra = 0;
        int hydra = 999;
        string hydraString = hydra.ToString();

        while (true)
        {
            string ultraString = ultra.ToString();
            Console.Write(ultraString);
            ultra++;
            int requiredSpaces = Console.BufferWidth - ultraString.Length - hydraString.Length;
            Console.Write(new string(' ', requiredSpaces));
            Console.Write(hydraString);
        }
```

Also, I don't know why you're putting this in an infinite loop, this will use 100% CPU usage, if you would like to be safer, add a Thread.Sleep between each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explore a bit with the Console.Write. You put a fix number of space bars, so when ultra is small, you have less characters over all and that's why the rows don't fill up the same. And because you have less characters, the numbers keep going left.

This was to answer your question, but now I have some suggestions. Even in an infinite loop like this, you can pause the process by clicking anywhere inside your console (you can resume it by pressing any key afterwards). So pause the process and resize the width of your console. At one time, there will be 3 perfect columns, and then 2 perfect columns if you shrink it enough. This will further strengthen my previous point.

And now, if I understand correctly, you want two columns. first, you should use the "tab" character instead of white spaces - it is a special character, you can write "\t" inside your string to access it. You can put multiple of these. And now, for two columns, check if ultra is an even number and insert a new line. The code should look something like this:

```
    int ultra = 0;
    int hydra = 999;

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write(ultra);
        ultra++;
        Console.Write($"\t\t\t{hydra}");
        if(ultra % 2 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine();
    }
```